# Html within Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I am creating a karaoke type website, I simply want to add HTML with the words. I also want to add a break tag so some lyrics are showing on the second page.

The codepen is here:- https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/OJPRyXy

As you can see I have tried adding in a break tag, but this isn't outputting as HTML. I understand this, but is there a way to change this?

Can anyone help with this?

```js
  var lyricsText = [
  {
      "text": "Intro <br>Ding Dong Merrily on High",
      "duration": 3900
  }];

  var player = new Vue({
    el: '#player',

    data: {
      lyrics: {
        show: false,
        timer: null,
        currentLine: '',
        text: lyricsText,
      },

      song : {
        progress: 0
      },

      audio: null,

      playing: false,

      playerTouched: false
    },

    ready: function() {
      // Setup the audio element
      this.audio = this.$els.audio;

      // Setup time tracker updates
      this.audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', this.updateTimeTracker, false);

      // Setup end reset
      this.audio.addEventListener('ended', this.resetPlayer, false);
    },

    methods: {
      hideText: function() {
        this.lyrics.show = !this.lyrics.show;
      },

      startPlayback: function() {
          this.playing = true;

          this.audio.volume = 0.5;
          this.audio.play();

          this.lyrics.show = true;
          this.displayNextLine(0);
      },

      togglePlayback: function() {
        if (!this.playerTouched) {
          this.startPlayback();
          this.playerTouched = true;
          return;
        }

        this.playing = !this.playing;

        if (this.audio.paused) {
          this.audio.play();
          this.resumeLyrics();
        } else {
          this.audio.pause();
          this.pauseLyrics();
        }
      },

      pauseLyrics: function() {
        if (this.lyrics.timer) {
          this.lyrics.timer.pause();
        }
      },

      resumeLyrics: function() {
        if (this.lyrics.timer) {
          this.lyrics.timer.resume();
        }
      },

      displayNextLine: function(line) {
        var _this = this;

        // Set the currentLine, which will auto display
        _this.lyrics.currentLine = _this.lyrics.text[line].text;

        if (_this.lyrics.text[line + 1] !== undefined) {
          _this.lyrics.timer = new Timer(function() {
            _this.displayNextLine(line + 1);
          }, _this.lyrics.text[line].duration);
        } 
        //else {
           // _this.lyrics.currentLine = 'THE END';
        //}      
      },

      updateTimeTracker: function() {
        this.song.progress = 100 * (this.audio.currentTime / this.audio.duration);
      },

      resetPlayer: function() {
        this.playing = false;
        this.playerTouched = false;
      }
    }

  });

  function Timer(callback, delay) {
      var timerId;
      var start;
      var remaining = delay;

      this.pause = function() {
          window.clearTimeout(timerId);
          remaining -= new Date() - start;
      };

      this.resume = function() {
          start = new Date();
          window.clearTimeout(timerId);
          timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
      };

      this.resume();
  }
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.0-rc.2/vue.js"></script>

  <div class="Player" id="player">

    <audio src="dd.mp3" 
           v-el:audio></audio>

    <div class="Player__cover" @click="hideText">
      <div class="Player__lyrics">
        <div class="line"
             v-if="lyrics.show" 
             v-text="lyrics.currentLine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Player__track"
         :style="{ width: song.progress + '%' }"></div>

    <div class="Player__controls">
      <i class="icon play material-icons" 
         v-text="playing ? 'pause_circle_filled' : 'play_circle_filled'"
         @click="togglePlayback"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, you're using `v-text`; I would think you'd want `v-html`, but I don't really know Vue.

Comment: You are correct!! Thanks so much, been looking for ages within JS and didnt realise it was in the HTML!

Answer (score 1):

Try using v-html directive instead of v-text on your HTML.

```html
<div class="line" v-if="lyrics.show" v-html="lyrics.currentLine"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two main ways to create elements in Javascript. The first is to use `createElement()` function:

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "I'm a div";
div.id = "myDiv";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```css
#myDiv{
   color: red;
}
```

The second is to use the `innerHTML` property on an existing element:

```js
const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
div.innerHTML = "<p>I'm a p tag</p>";
```

```css
p{
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: @Brad inject is as the innerHTML of an existing element